# how do I use different starting points when processing EACH results?

Tags: arrays, ruby, each

I am having trouble joining data where one piece of data in an array element relates to the next element. Here is the basic string.

classes = ["Tue Oct 6, 2015\n8:00am\nAmerican History 9am\nAP Engineering10am\nModern Film 11:00am\nGeometry 1pm\n English 2:00pm\nPhysical Education 3pm\nArt", "", ""]

I split the string into an array based on newline, which made it readable.

classes = events.split("\n")

classes = ["Tue Oct 6, 2015","8:00am","American History 9am","AP Engineering10am","Modern Film 11:00am","Geometry 1pm"," English 2:00pm","Physical Education 3pm","Art", "", ""]

The trouble is, after the first time (8:00am), all subsequent times are the last "word" in each element except the last one. Bad web design, I guess.

The correct output I am trying to assemble is:

Tue Oct 6, 2015
8:00am American History
9am AP Engineering
10am Modern Film 
11:00am Geometry 
1pm English 
2:00pm Physical Education 
3pm Art

Here is my run at the code.

`my_array = classes.drop(2)`

```
date = classes.first
time1 = classes[1][0...6] 
class1 = classes[2][0...55]
class1_trim = class1[/(.*)\s/,1]

p date
p "#{time1} #{class1_trim}"



x = my_array.length
y = x-1

(0..y).each do |k|

class_k = my_array[k][0...55]
class_k_trim = class_k[/(.*)\s/,1] 
time_k = my_array[k][0...55].split(/\s+/).last

if k < y
p "#{time_k} #{class_k_trim}"
else
p "#{time_k} #{class_k}"  #no need for trim on last element

end

end
```

The problem is, the time and the class get out of sync because they start on different elements.

I need to use the time from the second element of my_array, joined with the  class from the third element. Then the time from the third element is the start time for the fourth element, and so on.

Can anyone help me do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you don't have to do the split:

```
classes.first.tr(?\n, " ")
=> "Tue Oct 6, 2015 8:00am American History 9am AP Engineering10am Modern Film 11:00am Geometry 1pm  English 2:00pm Physical Education 3pm Art"
```

No space before the 10 though. Is that a typo?

Edit:

```
classes.first.split(?\n).each_cons(2).to_a
=> [["Tue Oct 6, 2015", "8:00am"], ["8:00am", "American History 9am"], ["American History 9am", "AP Engineering 10am"], ["AP Engineering 10am", "Modern Film 11:00am"], ["Modern Film 11:00am", "Geometry 1pm"], ["Geometry 1pm", " English 2:00pm"], [" English 2:00pm", "Physical Education 3pm"], ["Physical Education 3pm", "Art"]]
```

should get you there. You'll have to treat the first and last elements as special cases though.

Comment: Yes, that's a typo. The original data has "\n" between the school classes. The problem is, when I drop the first 2 elements and start on the 3rd element, "American History 9:00am", the only useful info is the time, "9:00am", which is actually the time for the 4th element, "Ap Engineering". How can I "save" the time and use it in the next cycle, when I capture "Ap Engineering" ?

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it tonight.

Comment: Thanks, Seph. I just ran the code. I had to take "first " out before split because Ruby threw a NoMethod error. Once I did that, the output looked just like yours, and the data elements are grouped in a way I can use. As soon as I figure out how to Accept your answer, I will.